# Constructor is undefined in Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-arrayadapter

I know this has been solved a million times and yes i have searched, but it doesn't work for me.

The problem is that method **super** doesn't want proper arguments.

The code:

```
public class QuotesArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map<Integer,List<String>>> {
private Context context;
Map<Integer,List<String>> Values;
static int textViewResId;
Logger Logger;

public QuotesArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Map<Integer,List<String>> object) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, object);   //<---- ERROR HERE
    this.context = context;
    this.Values = object;
    Logger = new Logger(true);
    Logger.l(Logger.TAG_DBG, "ArrayAdapter Inited");
}
```

What Eclipse says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The constructor ArrayAdapter<Map<Integer,List<String>>>(Context, int, Map<Integer,List<String>>) 
 is undefined
- The constructor ArrayAdapter<Map<Integer,List<String>>>(Context, int, Map<Integer,List<String>>) 
 is undefined
```

It wants **super(Context, int)** and that's not what i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the constructors available for [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

*None* of those matches your arguments.

Which one did you intend to invoke? Your `T` here is `Map<Integer,List<String>>`, but your constructor's `object` parameter is of exactly that type. If you want to use one of the constructors which requires a *collection*, you need to build that collection from that single object you've got.

The simplest approach is probably just to use:

```
public QuotesArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                          Map<Integer,List<String>> object) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    add(object);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh i got it! I changed arguments and it worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: @DrBigNik (While my answer is not superior.) By calling `add(object)` you will create a `List<Map<Integer, List<String>>>` with one item... I wouldn't put "efficient" among the potential adjectives for this Collection.  I highly recommend restructuring your data to simply use a List or writing the adapter that you do want yourself. (I'll give Jon Skeet an upvote anyway for making it work.)

Comment: Yeah i think i will write my own Adapter, 'cause using a List will not be good in my situation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply there is no constructor in [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) that takes a Map...

You need to convert it into a List or primitive Array, if neither of those options work then you will have to extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In additional you can use `Arrays.asList(..)`

```
public QuotesArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Map<Integer,List<String>> object) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId,  Arrays.asList(object));   
....
```